How to count exact text string matches when there is a partial text string overlap, such as counting both pills and pillaged pills but not pillaged
I am flummoxed but confident there is a way to do this. I just can’t see it.
I want to count the number of class options for each age, but I can't figure out a way to count ‘5 y/o’ without also counting ‘15 y/o’ — or a way to count all classes for ‘5 y/o’ including those that are also for ‘15 y/o’.
My downloaded data looks like this:



Class
Age(s)




Class Title 1
0 y/o,1 y/o,2 y/o,3 y/o,4 y/o,5 y/o,6 y/o,7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 2
1 y/o,2 y/o,3 y/o,4 y/o,5 y/o,6 y/o,7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 3
2 y/o,3 y/o,4 y/o,5 y/o,6 y/o,7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 4
3 y/o,4 y/o,5 y/o,6 y/o,7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 5
4 y/o,5 y/o,6 y/o,7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 6
5 y/o,6 y/o,7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 7
6 y/o,7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 8
7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 9
8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 10
9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 11
10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 12
10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o


Class Title 13
10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o


Class Title 14
0 y/o,1 y/o,2 y/o,3 y/o,4 y/o,5 y/o,6 y/o,7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o


Class Title 15
3 y/o,4 y/o,5 y/o,6 y/o


Class Title 16
5 y/o,6 y/o,7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o


Class Title 17
0 y/o,1 y/o,2 y/o,3 y/o,4 y/o,5 y/o,6 y/o,7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 18
1 y/o,2 y/o,3 y/o,4 y/o,5 y/o,6 y/o,7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 19
2 y/o,3 y/o,4 y/o,5 y/o,6 y/o,7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o


Class Title 20
3 y/o,4 y/o,5 y/o,6 y/o,7 y/o,8 y/o,9 y/o,10 y/o,11 y/o,12 y/o,13 y/o,14 y/o,15 y/o,16 y/o,17 y/o,18 y/o,19 y/o



The results that I are want are:



Age
Number of Class Options for Age




0 y/o
3


1 y/o
5


2 y/o
7


3 y/o
10


4 y/o
11


5 y/o
13


6 y/o
14


7 y/o
14


8 y/o
15


9 y/o
16


10 y/o
18


11 y/o
17


12 y/o
17


13 y/o
17


14 y/o
17


15 y/o
16


16 y/o
16


17 y/o
16


18 y/o
16


19 y/o
15


Adult 20+
0



If it matters, the number of classes varies by semester.
The following counts both classes for ‘5 y/o’ and classes for ‘15 y/o’ that are not also for ‘5 y/o’
=COUNTIFS('data sheet'!$A$2:$A,"<>",'data sheet'!$B$2:$B,"*"&A2&"*")
The following fails to count classes that are for both ‘5 y/o’ and  ‘15 y/o’.
=COUNTIFS('data sheet'!$A$2:$A,"<>",'data sheet'!$B$2:$B,"*"&A2&"*",'data sheet'!$B$2:$B,"<>*"&A12&"*")
Thank you.
link to editable Google Sheet


Here's one approach you may adapt accordingly:
=arrayformula(countif(","&'data sheet'!B:B&",","*,"&B2:B22&",*"))



Another solution:
=MAP(B2:B22,LAMBDA(x,SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH('data sheet'!B:B,"\b"&x)))) 

